# PUSH уведомления

Tags: android, ios, уведомления

В проекте необходимо реализовать механизм PUSH уведомлений.
Проект идет на двух платформах - Android и iOS.

Есть конкретные вопросы.

1. Мне обязательно надо регистрировать приложения в сервисах - APNS для iOS и GCM для Android или это можно избежать если пользоваться сторонними сервисами?
2. Как получить уникальный регистрационный TOKEN для iOS и Андроид, какие библиотеки для этого используются?
3. Какие сервисы вы можете посоветовать для упрощения данной задачи? Желательно с хорошей документацией по описанию API и примерами приложений для каждой из платформ.
4. Ну и возможно вы посоветуете для каждой из платформ хорошие статьи с примерами, где все объясняется по пунктам.

Comment: Слишком много вопросов в одном.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Отвечу только по части **iOS**:

1. Да, надо.
2. Ответ на этот вопрос содержится [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8798725/get-device-token-for-push-notification). Никакие
   библиотеки не нужны, главное помнить, что токен можно получить, и,
   соответственно, протестировать только на реальном устройстве, а не
   симуляторе.
3. Чтобы протестировать приём уведомлений можете воспользоваться [этой утилитой.](https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher)
4. Могу посоветовать [вот эту статью](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/setting-up-push-notifications-on-ios--cms-21925) и [вот это видео.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kF_tM9xxT_8)

Answer (score 1):

Есть кроссплатформенные реализации Push нотификаций. Например копните [Amazon Web Services](https://aws.amazon.com) или [parse.com](http://www.parse.com) (parse.com по моему реализован на AWS)